# macOS not allowing me to change file permissions though I am the sole user/admin

Tags: macos, mac, finder, permission

macOS is not permitting me to change the file permissions of any file! whenever I try to add the admin which is me, finder gives me this error:

you don't have necessary permission - operation not permitted

In spite of the fact that I am the sole user

I have tried chmod, again same error - operation not permitted

The permissions are as follows!

[image]

Screenshot of the operation not permitted error I getting

[image]

Comment: Which file/folder are you trying to change permissions for?

Comment: @patrix System Files!

Comment: The first screenshot shows your home folder, the second Terminal.app, why do you think they are related? Also, macOS-installed files are protected by SIP and can‘t be changed by any user.

Comment: @patrix I attached the first screenshot cause terminal falls under the home folder and I might be wrong but don't you think that changing permissions of the home folder changes the permission of everything inside it?

Comment: @patrix I know about SIP and I have posted this question after disablling it, but still I get this error!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do here. The first screenshot shows your home directory, the second one the error you get when trying to change permissions on `Terminal.app`. `Terminal.app` is stored in `/Applications/Utilities`, there is no relation to the home directory as such. Changing the permissions of applications which are part of macOS is not possible as all of them are protected by SIP.